# Create iframe and listen when complete loading

Tags: jquery, iframe, listener

I have a function that is creating an iframe which delivers a zip for download.
I would like to trigger another function as soon as the iframe has completed loading but I cannot do that by echoing anything from the iframe src because that one has  file headers in it's php.
I have found instructions for listening for load event but seems something is beyond my understanding:

```
 function downloadZIP(structure) {
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://www.example.com/<?=$work_folder?>/zip.php?structure="+structure+"&alpha=<?=$_GET['alpha']?>");
ifrm.style.width = 640+"px";
ifrm.style.height = 480+"px";
ifrm.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);

ifrm.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( ifrm.readyState == 'complete' ) {
        //iframeIsLoaded();  
        alert('loaded');
        }
    }
}
```

Pure javascript or jquery suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

## Parent.html

```
function iframeLoaded() {
    console.log("[[IFRAME LOADED]]");
}
```

## child.html

```
window.onload = function() {
    parent.iframeLoaded();
}
```

When the document inside the iframe (`child.html`) is loaded, it's last function will be to call `iframeLoaded()` which is on the parent page (`parent.html`). When the function `iframeLoaded()` is called from the child page, you can place a callback or whatever else.

---

---

Another way would use an `onload event handler` on the iframe itself.

`<iframe id="ifrm" src="demo.html" onload="doSomething()"></iframe>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {
// put your awesome code here
}
</script>
```

For this and more on iframes go [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/onload/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jquery.[load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)()

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
alert('loaded');
});
```